# How do I pass an optional event handler to a svelte component?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I have a re-usable component `Tags.svelte` and I want to optionally pass a click handler:

```html
<Tags {tags} {clickHandler} />
```

I can make the parameter optional but I don't know how to attach it to my tag `<button>` item in the component if its optional

Normally I would do:

```html
<button on:click|preventDefault={clickHandler}>{tag}</button>
```

but how do I make this optional?

Comment: What is the problem? As long as the `clickHandler` is declared, it can be optional (`undefined`) without issue. Also: You should not attach event handlers to otherwise non-interactive elements; it is not accessible. Click handlers should be attached to elements like `button` (which can be styled to be unobtrusive).

Comment: what would happen if i did `on:click|preventDefault={undefined}`? I have an `href` sometimes and sometimes a click handler.

Comment: I made it a button.

Comment: If you explicitly set `undefined` it will cause an error, if you use a variable which is `undefined` it will simply do nothing (Svelte will check if the variable is a function before trying to call it).

Comment: Is there a reason the handler must be passed? Should the content of the component  change depending on the fact if it's defined or not? Because otherwise the listener could also just be set inside the component `<button on:click|preventDefault>{tag}</button>` and handled in the parent on the component `<Tags {tags} on:click={clickHandler} />`

Comment: *"I can make the parameter optional"* I assume that you mean by 'make it optional', that you give it a default value, so that there's no warning *'<Component> was created without expected prop'* if it's not passed? So if the prop is supposed to be a function, why not set the default like this `export let clickHandler = () => {}`

Comment: Generally forwarding the event is the preferred approach. If you export the handler as a prop you can either set it to `undefined` or `() => {}`, both will do nothing.

Comment: I think the best solution is to emit an event to the parent who can handle the click or do nothing.

Comment: A `<button>` that 'does nothing' when clicked on by the user should simply not be a button. HTML semantics matter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple `{#if}` block to branch out what is rendered:

```js
<script>
  export let tags
  export let clickHandler    # undefined and will evaluate to false if not set, will evaluate to true if set
</script>

{#each tags as tag}
  {#if clickHandler}
    <button on:click|preventDefault={clickHandler}>{tag}</button>
  {:else}
    <span>{tag}</span>
  {/if}
{/each}
```